# How to copy files to sourceforge in non-interactive request for password?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, terminal, github

I want to automate the copying of files to Sourceforge with GitHub Actions.

I get problems when I copy files in non-interactive mode. For eg:
`scp <file on laptop> <folder in sourceforge host>` without password and do it from Github Action or any other CI.

I need a way to copy files to sourceforge without an interactive request for a password.

ERROR in GitHub Action:

```
Please provide password for USERNAME,XYZ@shell.sourceforge.net
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Comment: Not familiar with this particular scenario, but could you use something like `expect` to pass it in? Or `sshpass`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [github action](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action) (appleboy/scp-action) for copying files vi `scp`.

Using:

```
name: scp files
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: copy file via ssh password
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        source: "tests/a.txt,tests/b.txt"
        target: "test"
```